# Rate table shipping showing $0.00 only for certain products

Tags: shipping, magento-1.9, table-rates, estimate

I've added four nearly identical products to my brand new Magento 1.9 store. Each one with complete information, including weights.

Then I set up a shipping rate table, and successfully imported the CSV. I confirmed this in the "shipping_tablerate" db table using phpMyAdmin. The CSV that I'm using for debugging looks like this:

```
Country,Region/State,Zip/Postal Code,Weight (and above),Shipping Price
USA,*,*,0,1000
```

This rate is reflected correctly for one of my products when I add it to the cart and estimate shipping. However, for my remaining three products, it estimates shipping to be $0.00.

I can't figure out what is causing this odd behavior for the life of me.

**65 lb product (??? $0.00 rate)**

[image: 65 lb product (??? $0.00 rate)]

**85 lb product (correct $1000.00 rate)**

[image: 85 lb product (correct $1000.00 rate)]

Any ideas? I've burnt most of the day on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes in my mind:

1. is it a simple item, not a virtual one
2. has it set weight
3. is there any rule or setting on the item, for free shipping
4. is there some rule for free shipping from 700$ or something

Comment: It was the result of a promotion. So basically #4 on your list. Thank you so much! It didn't even occur to me. Ugh. The demo content and settings can be just as much a curse as they can be a blessing.

Comment: There is _NO_ reason to built a shop on demo data. Beside of the collateral damage like this, the data are broken